# show/hide menu with jquery not working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

In Google Chrome Only:
For some reason the show hide menu is not working on this site (click "About Us" left): 
http://tinyurl.com/6s34ww9

But it works when I isolate it:
http://jsbin.com/xuzoweda/1/edit

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I step through your JS line by line I never see it working. It's setting the classes and such as you intend though. I'm thinking it might be this line in your CSS:

```
#nav li ul.current {
  display:block;
}
```

Should probably be:

```
#nav li.current ul {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: for some reason in the css #nav li ul the "float:left" was causing it to not show in chrome. Not sure why but it worked.